# Cannot calculate robust standard errors (vcovHC): multicollinearity and NaN error

Tags: r, standard-error, robust

I have the following dataset:

```
share <- c(-0.16,-0.07,0,0,-0.06,-0.06,-0.18,-0.23,-0.07,-0.24,0,0,-0.22,-0.15,0,0,-0.09,-0.2,0,-0.19,0,-0.16,-0.24,-0.14,-0.22,-0.22,0,-0.18,0,0,-0.01,0,0,-0.14,0,-0.06,0,-0.12,0,0,-0.14,0,0,0,-0.02,0,0,0,0,0,-0.19,0,-0.21,-0.08,0,0,0,-0.1,-0.17,0,0,-0.13,-0.08,-0.1,0,-0.05,-0.06,0,0,-0.1,0,0,0,-0.16,0,-0.18,-0.04,-0.08,0,-0.06,0,0,0,-0.2,0,0,-0.08,0,0,-0.01,0,-0.16,-0.08,0,0,0,-0.02,-0.18,0.17,-0.2,-0.14,0,-0.24)
grade <- c(-22.64,-2.39,-15.3,-22.34,-6.39,5.25,0.47,33.61,-0.54,-25.21,16.41,-13.94,21.04,-19.64,-7.48,-32.18,-19.48,21.65,0.88,-1.6,28.49,13.61,-1.69,19.34,2.19,-7.25,6.65,7.25,20.56,16.25,17.24,12.3,3.7,-8.64,8.25,3.27,6,14.32,0.91,8.6,-6.84,13.35,6.99,3.36,0.29,19.46,2,10.75,8.76,-6.54,36.46,28.88,0.44,4.73,3.52,-10.7,-3.88,-2.36,-15.12,9.55,-4.96,10.7,6.84,-10.98,13.03,3.46,14.65,-1.66,6.89,-11.47,-6.52,15.64,3.02,4.11,-8.41,4.77,18.97,-3.73,9.54,-6.06,13.1,-24.62,-2.5,-30.26,3.82,12.97,4,2.21,14.33,12.47,-55.11,19.86,13.7,9.19,-11.01,-2.52,13.1,3.83,1.51,4.18,-3.14,-5.85,8.39)
treat <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
dataset <- as.data.frame(cbind(share, grade, treat))
```

I want to run the following linear model and calculate robust standard errors by using the `sandwich` package.

```
library(sandwich)
model <- lm(grade ~ treat + share + treat*share, dataset)
robSE <- sqrt(diag(vcovHC(model, type = "HC2")))
```

The output of the linear model is fine, but the robust standard errors are not calculated: `NaN` is returned for each standard error.

My guess is that the `NaN` is due to the variables `treat` and `share` being almost perfectly collinear (there is only one observation in which `treat=1` and `share!=0`). The problem is that I must use these variables; I cannot replace them.

Does someone can think of a workaround/solution to this issue?

Comment: Do you need "HC2" absolutely? HC0 and HC1 give non-NaN results (btw you might get better luck on Cross Validated, a site more stats focused than SO)

Comment: @DominicComtois: You are right twice, HC1 works and Cross Validated would be better. I did some reading and will use HC1. I will post the rationale of such a choice as an answer to this question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some reading and following @DominicComtois suggestion, I think here I will have to go with `HC1`. `HC3`, `HC4` (Long and Ervin 2000, Hayes and Cai 2007), or `HC4m` (Cribari-Neto and Silva 2011) would be better, but they all give NaN results. The problem with `HC0` is that it tends to be biased in small to moderately large samples (Hayes and Cai 2007, Cribari-Neto and Silva 2011).

References

Cribari-Neto F., da Silva W.B. (2011). A new heteroskedasticity-consistent covariance matrix estimator for the linear regression model. Adv Stat Anal 95:129–146.

Hayes, A. F., & Cai, L. (2007). Using heteroscedasticity-consis- tent standard error estimators in OLS regression: An intro- duction and software implementation. Behavior Research Methods, 39, 709–722.

Long, J.S., Ervin, L.H. (2000). Using heteroscedasticity-consistent standard errors in the linear regression model. Am. Stat. 54, 217–224.